# How can i use Symfony or Zend Components inside Code Igniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like if there is a simple and clean way to use ZF´s (or Symfony´s) component library in a CodeIgniter application, because there is a lot of good and useful stuff there that CI don´t have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It´s possible. For example for ZF, you would need to do something like:

1) Setup CodeIgniter.

2) Download the Zend Framework. Extract the archive.

3) From the ZF files, copy the “Zend” directory from inside the “library” directory.

4) Paste the directory into the “`system/application/libraries`” directory. 
So ultimately, the new location of the copied “Zend” directory would be “`system/application/libraries/Zend`”. 
If you’re on Linux/Unix, we probalby will need to deal with file permissions. 
I guess you will need to make the Zend directory accessible by all (use chmod).

5) In the same “system/application/libraries/” directory, create a new file named “Zend.php” and put the following contents:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) {exit('No direct script access allowed');}

class Zend
{

  function __construct()
  {

    ini_set('include_path',
    ini_get('include_path') . PATH_SEPARATOR . APPPATH . 'libraries');

  }


  function load($class)
  {
    require_once (string) $class . EXT;

  }
}

?>
```

Now test the setup using the CI´s default Welcome controller

```
<?php

class Welcome extends Controller {

  function Welcome()
  {
    parent::Controller();
  }

  function index()
  {
     $this->load->library('zend');
     $this->zend->load('Zend/Service/Flickr');

    $flickr = new Zend_Service_Flickr('12e99caebb8f305fff5a943606ecde18');

    $results = $flickr->tagSearch('worldcup');



    foreach ($results as $result)
    {

        $photo = $result->Small;
        echo "<a href=\"{$photo->clickUri}\"><img src=\"{$photo->uri}\" /></a><br /><br />";

    }

  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use components symfony by installing them via composer.

For example, you can install the [varDumper](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html) component which provides a better `dump()` function that you can use instead of `var_dump`.

```
composer require symfony/var-dumper
```

the composer will install the dumper component with all his dependecy

then include the autoload and use the dump function

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

// create a variable, which could be anything!
$someVar = ...;

dump($someVar);
```